# Get a random number in using a function in JS and reuse that number

Tags: javascript, function, object, random

I am trying to get a random element within an array, inside an object. I want to reuse that random element for another property in an object.

The problem is the function is trying to generate a random number again every time I call that.

For example, the `object.randomWord()` will return a different result than the `object.wordSplit()`.

How to make sure all properties reference the same random element?

Thanks.

```js
var object = {
  wordArray: ["falconheavy", "roadster", "tesla", "openai"],
  randomWord: function() {
    return this.wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.wordArray.length)];
  },
  wordSplit: function() {
    return this.randomWord().split('');
  },
}
console.log(object.randomWord()); //"falconheavy"
console.log(object.wordSplit()); // ["t","e","s","l","a"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? LocalStorage, cookies  or simply a variable in the object come to mind

Comment: Why don't you save the randomWord to a variable, and then split that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, In your code you can also do like this

**DEMO**

```js
var object = {
  wordArray: ["falconheavy", "roadster", "tesla", "openai"],
  randomWord: function() {
    this.randomNo = this.wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.wordArray.length)];
    return this.randomNo;
  },
  wordSplit: function() {
    return (this.randomNo||'').split('');
  }
}

console.log(object.randomWord()); 
console.log(object.wordSplit());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Another way, As you use to method `randomWord()` and `wordSplit()`. Inside of `wordSplit()` you again getting random number so instead of this you can first get random number and store in variable and again pass that value into `wordSplit()` for splitting.

**DEMO**

```js
var object = {
  wordArray: ["falconheavy", "roadster", "tesla", "openai"],
  randomWord: function() {
    return this.wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.wordArray.length)];
  },
  wordSplit: function(v) {
    return v.split('');
  }
}
let result = object.randomWord();
console.log(result); 
console.log(object.wordSplit(result));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I want to call the object property without storing it to a new variable outside the object. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply store the result of calling `randomWord` in a variable, and pass that as an argument to `wordSplit`, like so:

```
var object = {
  wordArray: ["falconheavy", "roadster", "tesla", "openai"],
  randomWord: function() {
    return this.wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.wordArray.length)];
  },
  wordSplit: function(word) {
    return word.split('');
  },
}

var randWord = object.randomWord();

console.log(randWord);
console.log(object.wordSplit(randWord));
```